# Real normal matrix which is diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ but not unitary diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

Let $A$ be a **real** $n\times n$ matrix. Can $A$ be normal, diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ but not unitary diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$ ? By "unitary diagonalizable over $\mathbb{R}$" I mean that there exist a real unitary matrix $P$ such that $P^tAP$ is diagonal.

**My attempt:** I need to find a non-symmetric real matrix which is normal ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix#Equivalent_definitions

Comment: Thanks, but what I suppose to take from that page?

Comment: It says: "the following are equivalent: 1. A is normal. 2. A is diagonalizable by a unitary matrix.". But I guess this does not readily explain the case over $\mathbb{R}$. I believe it does after some thinking though...

Comment: So you think that such a matrix does not exists?

Comment: indeed, I believe so. See also [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_diagonalization)

Answer (score 2):

No. If $A$ is normal, it is unitarily diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$. Let $A=UDU^\ast$ be such a diagonalisation. Since $A$ is supposed to be diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$, $D$ is a real diagonal matrix. Therefore $A$ is Hermitian. Yet, $A$ is real. Hence it is real symmetric and unitarily/orthogonally diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$.